# Match div height to height of flexible image

Tags: html, css, less

Currently I'm using just HTML and LESS CSS...

I've set my img tag to have a `max-width: 100%` so that, essentially, my images are all flexible and sized perfectly to the window/screen that they are viewed in/on.

Containing the images are divs, whose widths are **always** 100%, but, whose heights need to match that of the images.

How can I get the divs the same height as the (flexible) images? Is there any way to do this just with HTML and LESS CSS or is Javascript required?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: there's no way getting around CSS for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [set equal height on multiple divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473041/set-equal-height-on-multiple-divs)

Comment: @Diodeus Nothing like that question/problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can use a clearfix for this...

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

add ".clearfix" to your div containing the img.

Comment: Thank you very much, seems like a stupid error on my part! Just one more thing is that there seems to be a strange 6px gap at the bottom, between my image and the bottom of the div, even after adding .clearfix and making the image 6px bigger! http://c.sebj.me/emKL

Comment: You must have some margin or padding added to the div somewhere. to the img or to the div. Can you mark this answer as your choice please?

Answer (score 0):

try the following css:

`overflow:auto;`

on all of the `div`s that the image is in.